# Sealing computer case against sea spray / maritime salt

Tags: water-cooling

I live in an area with a very heavy sea spray incidence. The sea spray is so heavy that most desktops I have here don't last past an year without changing a few parts, and even the laptops (usually used on rooms with a/c) don't last past 18 months.

I was thinking I could use water cooling together with a silicone gun to seal the computer case. Should it work? Any other suggestion to avoid corrosion? (I read about varnish here and might try that instead.)

I am trying to upload some pictures from my phone so that you can get an idea of how strong the sea spray is.

EDIT: http://postimg.org/gallery/3ef5n8fke/ gallery with 2 pics. There is a little amount of dust there (pre-cleaning) however you can see the rust. This case is ONLY 6 months old.

Comment: why dont you use air purifiers in your room?

Comment: Something I would try would be desiccant packets. Maybe tape some to the inside of the case? How about putting some silica sand in a cheese cloth satchel? Just some crazy ideas which may work. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: There used to be an outfit called Hardcore Computer which sold a totally immersed, liquid cooled system.  However, a couple of years back they renamed to LiquidCool Solutions and focused on servers, so I'm not sure if they sell individual boxes any more.  You might pick up one used, though.

Comment: You might want to consider putting anti-corrosion vapour capsules/pads inside your PC before you seal it up as it has already been exposed to the atmosphere. e.g. http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/anti-corrosion-vapour-capsules/2973130/

Comment: The other option would be to seal the equipment inside an airtight case and install some sort of heat exchanger.  A "mini-split" air conditioner would do it, though it would be bulky, cost at least $700, and likely be too large, cooling-wise.  (A standard window AC unit would be a poor choice since they're designed to bring in fresh air.)

Comment: Are certain parts more prone to fail than others?

Comment: I have had 2 problems with VGA, I'd say they are the more prone to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting problem.

Oil is a pretty good guard against salt.  While this might seem a strange cure, how about coating your equipment with a thin coating of oil, like perhaps WD-40 inside in every cavity?  Not having tested this myself, your results may vary.  You will need make sure any parts like the fan are working afterwords.  And abandon the optical drive and instead use a USB one that you keep most of the time in a sealed plastic box.  I'm not sure if WD-40 contains any conductive ingredient, but I do know it is recommended to stop rust.  Then wipe off the keyboard so you can use it without too much mess.

And WD-40 stinks, so perhaps some other thin oil would be better for that reason.  You might have to kludge your own oil film sprayer by using a compressor and some sort of air-ator.  What comes to mind is the air-filter-oiler that I use with my compressor to send a little oil into the air flow for my air powered tools.

Many years ago I flew out to New Jersey to fix a poly peptide synthesizer in a chemical research facility there.  There were using a chemical called TFA, Tri Flouro something.  It was corroding the gold conductors on our circuit boards.  I was able to fix it but it soon failed again and soon the whole thing ended up in the dump.

Comment: When I was doing some research I found out that conformal coating is better than WD40 (it is supposed to help against rust but on a lower efficiency). I really liked the idea to abandon the optical drive. Would you coat your VGA with the gpu in (but without the cooler) or with the cooler?

Answer (score 0):

IF you water cool the CPU and GPU you can pretty much make the case air tight.  Put rubber gaskets around the holes you cut/drill for the water hoses.  If you can weld or know someone that does you can weld metal covers or over all the major openings.  You could probably find some other way to seal the openings closed also.  In addition you could have the power supply unit on the outside to allow air flow and so you can further seal the case.

You can also buy computers submerged in oil.(vegetable oil of some kind I think)
I don't think hard drives and optical drives are submerge able thou.

An SSD would probably solve the hard drive, if you are having issue with hard drive failures.

Comment: I'll look for water blocks for GPU in my country. I didnt think about putting the PSU outside, it should be needed too. I'll also check on how to submerge a computer in oil. This could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best you can do is use a sumerge in oil PC. There are a lot of videos and tutorials about how you can do this. For example: http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1663420/mineral-oil-submerged.html
I hope it helps!

Comment: This comes with a huge number of drawbacks which you may want to compare to the benefits of such a system.